# C++ Splay Tree implementation

Tags: c++, algorithm

I am coding a Splay Tree class in C++. I am looking for code review.

Currently, my Splay Tree class has search and rotate function.

I feel that I'm doing things overcomplicated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <regex>

using namespace std;

class TreeNode
{
public:
    int key;
    TreeNode* left = nullptr;
    TreeNode* right = nullptr;
    TreeNode(int key) {
        this->key = key;
    }
};

class SplayTree
{
public:
    SplayTree() {
        // This is temporary, will refactor later
        root = newNode(10);
        root->right = newNode(15);
        root->right->right = newNode(16);
        root->right->right->right = newNode(20);
        root->right->right->right->right = newNode(21);
        root->right->right->right->right->right = newNode(22);
    };
    ~SplayTree() {};
    TreeNode* newNode(int key)
    {
        TreeNode* Node = new TreeNode(key);
        return (Node);
    }

    TreeNode* rightRotate(TreeNode* x)
    {
        TreeNode* y = x->left;
        x->left = y->right;
        y->right = x;
        return y;
    }

    TreeNode* leftRotate(TreeNode* x)
    {
        TreeNode* y = x->right;
        x->right = y->left;
        y->left = x;
        return y;
    }

    void splay(int key)
    {
        if (this->root == nullptr) return;

        this->root = splaySub(this->root, key);

        // Odd edge
        if (this->root->key != key)
            this->root = (key < this->root->key) ? rightRotate(this->root) : leftRotate(this->root);
    }

    void search(int key)
    {
        splay(key);
    }

    void preOrder() {
        preOrder(this->root);
    }
    
private:
    void preOrder(TreeNode* root)
    {
        if (root != nullptr)
        {
            cout << root->key << " ";
            preOrder(root->left);
            preOrder(root->right);
        }
    }

    TreeNode* splaySub(TreeNode* root, int key) {
        if (root->key == key) return root;

        // Code deal with root->left
        if (key < root->key) {
            // Not found. Return last accessed node. Do as if we looked for current node's key
            if (root->left == nullptr) {
                key = root->key; // Modifies the outer-scoped variable
                return root;
            }

            root->left = splaySub(root->left, key);

            // Check if return path is odd
            if (root->left->key == key) return root;

            // Apply a double rotation, top-down:
            root = (key < root->key) ? rightRotate(root) : leftRotate(root);
            return root = (key < root->key) ? rightRotate(root) : leftRotate(root);
        }
        // Code deal with root->right
        else {
            if (root->right == nullptr) {
                key = root->key; 
                return root;
            }

            root->right = splaySub(root->right, key);

            if (root->right->key == key) return root;

            root = (key < root->key) ? rightRotate(root) : leftRotate(root);
            return root = (key < root->key) ? rightRotate(root) : leftRotate(root);
        }
    }

    TreeNode* root = nullptr;
};

int main()
{
    SplayTree Tree = SplayTree();

    Tree.search(20);
    Tree.preOrder();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `key = root->key; // Modifies the outer-scoped variable` does it?!

Comment: (I think the assignment to a parameter only has a chance to modify an outside-function value only if that parameter was passed by/as a reference. (Then again, I didn't code C++ *in anger* for two decades.))

Comment: I do in on purpose

Answer (score 1):

[Don’t](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721) write `using namespace std;`.

You can, however, in a CPP file (not H file) or inside a function put individual `using std::string;` etc.  (See [SF.7](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#sf7-dont-write-using-namespace-at-global-scope-in-a-header-file).)

---

```
    TreeNode(int key) {
        this->key = key;
    }
```

Use the base/member init list in your constructor, rather than assigning values in the body.  So:

```
    TreeNode(int key)
        : key{key} {}
```

---

Where's the destructor, copy constructor, etc?  Remember the **rule of three**.

It looks like you don't have any way of removing nodes at all, and leak memory if you discard the entire tree when you are done with it.

---

`if (this->root == nullptr) return;`

Don't do explicit comparisons against `nullptr`.  Don't write `this->` everywhere either!  This line would just be: `if (!root)  return;`

---

```
TreeNode* newNode(int key)
    {
        TreeNode* Node = new TreeNode(key);
        return (Node);
    }
```

What's the point of that?  I think you can rely on the constructor doing what it's supposed to and not need to make another function to create an instance of an object.

---

```
cout << root->key << " ";
```

Don't use a string where a char will do.  Use `' '` here instead of `" "`.

---

This code is duplicated:

```
          root = (key < root->key) ? rightRotate(root) : leftRotate(root);
          return root = (key < root->key) ? rightRotate(root) : leftRotate(root);
```

Try and make it back on the common branch rather than on both sides of a conditional statement, or stick it into a helper function.

Just looking at the code, I wonder if there is some subtle difference ... or were they supposed to be mirror images?  It's actually a lot of work and cognitive overhead to deal with duplication like this.

## P.S.

Otherwise, I think you're doing good.  Keep it up!  Your comments are meaningful and aid in reading the code.

## mirroring code

> Is there any way I can dynamically assign left or right to root? Like root[side] with side = "left"/"right"

Yes.  I've done this on a data structure that had a kind of [AVL tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree) at its heart.  I only needed one copy of each algorithm, such as rotating.  It could rotate to the left or rotate to the right with the same code.  This has a benefit in coverage testing too.

The key is to make the two different fields (left pointer and right pointer) an array of two things so they can be indexed.

```
   Treenode* children[2];  // left and right
```

Then, you can use an enumeration for `Left=0` and `Right=1`.  Now each function can take another parameter, say:

```
TreeNode* rightRotate (TreeNode* x, direction dir)
{
```

The first thing you do is set up *local* meanings for "this way" and "the other way".  I used *S* and *D* as the two logical directions (for *sinistral* and *dexteral*) instead of switching the meanings of the actual Left and Right locally.

```
    const direction S = dir;  // the way I'm going
    const direction S = 1-dir;  // the other way
```

I'm not showing the needed casting for "strong" types, just the underlying math that `1-dir` is always the other one.  In real code, this was a separate helper function that's used everywhere I have mirroring-enabled code.

Then your code becomes:

```
    TreeNode* y = x->children[S];
    x->children[S] = y->children[D];
    y->children[D] = x;
    return y;
}
```

That is, change `left` to `children[S]` and `right` to `children[D]`.

Comment: Thanks. It's a lot of insight

Comment: Is there any way I can dynamically assign left or right to root? Like root[side] with side = "left"/"right" (JavaScript can do this)

Comment: @TanNguyen I updated my post to answer this.  You can also look into _pointers to members_ to do what you can with JavaScript.  Though the way I showed is simple and generates very efficient code.

Answer (score 1):

I "feel" symmetries could be leveraged using references.

```
// to do: doc comment, decent variable names, access, const correctness
TreeNode* rotate(TreeNode* x, TreeNode *&y, TreeNode *&y_child)
{
    const TreeNode* r = y;
    y = y_child;
    y_child = x;
    return r;
}

TreeNode* rightRotate(TreeNode* x)
{
    return rotate(x, x->left, x->left->right);
}

TreeNode* leftRotate(TreeNode* x)
{
    return rotate(x, x->right, x->right->left);
}
```

Comment: (Um. Complicated. ?) Any takers?

Comment: No. It's okay. I'm thinking

Comment: Is there any way I can dynamically assign left or right to root? Like root[side] with side = "left"/"right" (JavaScript can do this)

Comment: (as in *dynamically add an object property*? No. That's easy in *prototypal* object modelling. I remember "morphing" Python objects.)

Comment: I added details for this to my Answer.

Comment: (@JDługosz Coincidentally, AVL is where I used Python object morphing (left-high, balanced, right-high). No need to waste one or even *two* bits in every node, is there?)

Comment: @greybeard I don't know what you are referring to with regards to wasting bits in each node.

Comment: (@JDługosz: traditionally, two "balance flags" are used with every "AVL node".)

Comment: @greybeard so you used the _type_ to represent which state it was in?  Clever.  If every object has the overhead of metadata (unlike C++, where if you don't have any virtual functions you get just the plain structure members you declared) that would save space.